# Python - get current fan speed & per CPU power consumption

Tags: python, linux

i'm looking for a way to get the current fan speed and per CPU Core power consumption in python.
external libraries are fine, but i prefer stuff you can get from pip and not to parse some linux bash tool result.
anything like that possible?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can read files in `/proc` to get cpu and fan status.

`/proc/cpuinfo` contains all cpus info in a format similar to yaml, so it's possible to use yaml lib to parse it:

```
import yaml

with open('/proc/cpuinfo', 'r') as fd: 
   stat = fd.read() 
   stat = stat.replace('\t', '') 
   stat = stat.split('\n\n') 
   l = [yaml.load(s) for s in stat] 
   print(l)
```

Unfortunately, as far as I know, fan status changes from hardware producer to producer. In my case I can read fan speed from `/proc/i8k`

Comment: Hi,sorry but cpuinfo doesn't provide power consumption AFAIK